# Twitter Bootstrap v3.0.0 not showing modal component

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on website that uses Bootstrap's modal feature.
When i use, `v3.0` of the bootstrap, the modal doesn't shows up, only the background is darkened. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/LgKUk/1/
However, when i only switch the `bootstrap.css to v2.3.2`, and not the **bootstrap.js**, then it works fine: As here: http://jsfiddle.net/CcNPP/
Is it a issue in v3.0 or some mistake i can't see.
Thanks

Note: jQuery used is v1.10

Comment: both fiddles using 2.3 css only

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @SridharR. Forgot to update. pls check back now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is updated the codes check it on fidlle it works fine..

**HTML**

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgKUk/2/